# 10 Screen, Two Separate PC day trading setup - Questions

Tags: hardware

Currently i have 6 monitors on one PC (4 are data streaming, 1 for trade execution, 1 for web browsing)

I would like 10 monitors, however, to reduce lag id like one PC to deal with data streaming, and one PC for web browsing / trade execution.

Here is a quick paint image of the PC setup that id like (two colors signify the differing PC's):

http://imageshack.us/f/46/6cm7.jpg/

Main questions:

Is there a program which will let me have the entire PC setup running with one mouse / keyboard seemlessly.

Is there a program which will let me switch tabs (chrome tabs) between one PC screen to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a program which will let me have the entire PC setup running
>   with one mouse / keyboard seemlessly.

Yes, [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) will do exactly that. It's an excellent program.

> Is there a program which will let me switch tabs (chrome tabs) between
>   one PC screen to the other?

No, not that I know of. That would be an impressive technical feat, though.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, would Synergy know that my PC's arent 'inline', i.e. will it be able to understand that certain PC monitors are in between other PC monitors?

Comment: Synergy has a very flexible configuration. You'll need to dig into it to see if it works for your specific application.

Comment: Appreciate the response, have a good weekend

Comment: Sure thing. If you apprecate this answer, please give back to the community by marking the answer as "accepted".